# What has been Alec Guinness's attitude toward Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, obi-wan-kenobi

<sub>inspired by [What has been Harrison Ford's attitude toward Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111992/14850)</sub>

I've heard claims here and there about Alec Guinness's attitude toward the *Star Wars* franchise, with some claiming that he hates it or used to hate it, etc.

Did he like *Star Wars* and then grew to dislike it? Or vice versa? If he ever did dislike *Star Wars*, then **why?** etc.

Basically, what has been Alec Guinness's attitude(s) towards *Star Wars*?

Comment: I hope you're not planning on asking about every SW actor's opinions on the films.

Comment: @Kevin Guinness and Ford are the only one's I'd heard didn't like SW. Have you heard of any others? :)

Comment: Actually, I heard about Ewan McGregor not being a great fan of his role...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### He was contemptuous towards Star Wars before he even started!

Here's what he wrote in a letter to a friend when he was first approached for a role in the original *Star Wars*:

> I have been offered a movie (20th Cent. Fox) which I may accept, if they come up with proper money. London and N. Africa, starting in mid-March. Science fiction – which gives me pause – but is to be directed by Paul [sic] Lucas who did "American Graffiti, which makes me feel I should. Big part. **Fairy-tale rubbish** but could be interesting perhaps.

And here's his commentary from while he was on set:

> ... new **rubbish dialogue** reaches me every other day on wadges of pink paper – and **none of it makes my character clear or even bearable**. I just think, thankfully, of the lovely bread, which will help me keep going until next April even if Yahoo collapses in a week ... I must off to studio and work with a dwarf (very sweet – and he has to wash in a bidet) and your fellow countrymen Mark Hamill and Tennyson (that can't be right) Ford. Ellison (? – No!) – well, a rangy, languid young man who is probably intelligent and amusing. But **Oh, God, God, they make me feel ninety – and treat me as if I was 106.** – Oh, Harrison Ford – ever heard of him?

(all emphasis mine; [source](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5974242/alec-guinness-thought-star-wars-was-fairytale-rubbish-and-harrison-fords-first-name-was-tennyson))

### And he remained unimpressed even years later.

From [this 1982 interview](http://www.rogerebert.com/interviews/interview-with-alec-guinness):

> But . . . the 'Star Wars' pictures. How did I like doing them? I liked the people very much. But, no, they're not really much fun to act in, not when you're put totally in the hands of technicians and asked to sit in a cylinder and imagine explosions. That's only amusing for a time.

Comment: Weren't you supposed to wait for my answer that said 'I don't have sources'? ;)

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7785/should-we-rename-the-star-wars-tag-to-fairy-tale-rubbish

Comment: So he never came around to it? He always disliked SW? That's so sad; he's my favorite SW character. :(

Comment: "even if Yahoo collapses in a week"?

Comment: @Dronz "Yahoo" was a play that Alec Guinness had a part in ([source](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000027/otherworks), [more info](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hyp2RoHMam0C&lpg=PA500&ots=P6CA4aEN-z&dq=yahoo%20play%201976&pg=PA499#v=onepage&q=yahoo%20play%201976&f=false)).

Comment: Here in the 21st century, Yahoo's collapse has taken a decade or more.

Comment: I believe I've read somewhere while he generally regarded Star Wars with disdain, he had no complaints on the steady stream of residuals it brought it.

Comment: I particularly enjoy that this accurate, on-point, well-cited answer has 1 downvote. Scifi.SE is a tough crowd! (or maybe it was Alec Guiness' ghost!)

Comment: @AndresF. On Christmas Eve, no less. Haters gonna hate, as the kids say these days.

Answer (score 29):

In addition to [rand al'thor's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111997/770), one anecdote about Alec Guinness which I find funny, and which illustrates his well-known dislike for Star Wars is this one:

A kid approached him, asking for his autograph and claiming to have seen *Star Wars* "a hundred times". Alec Guinness gave the autograph on the condition the kid promised him never to watch it again.

> A refurbished Star Wars is on somewhere or everywhere. I have no intention of revisiting any galaxy. I shrivel inside each time it is mentioned. Twenty years ago, when the film was first shown, it had a freshness, also a sense of moral good and fun. Then I began to be uneasy at the influence it might be having. The bad penny first dropped in San Francisco when a sweet-faced boy of twelve told me proudly that he had seen Star Wars over a hundred times. His elegant mother nodded with approval. Looking into the boy’s eyes I thought I detected little star-shells of madness beginning to form and I guessed that one day they would explode.
>
> “I would love you to do something for me,” I said.
>
> “Anything! Anything!” the boy said rapturously.
>
> “You won’t like what I’m going to ask you to do,” I said.
>
> “Anything, sir, anything!”
>
> “Well,” I said, “do you think you could promise never to see Star Wars again?”
>
> He burst into tears. His mother drew himself up to an immense height. “What a dreadful thing to say to a child!” she barked, and dragged the poor kid away. Maybe she was right but I just hope the lad, now in his thirties, is not living in a fantasy world of secondhand, childish banalities.

I knew this anecdote from a newspaper article, but Wikipedia gives the source as the book "A Positively Final Appearance" ([additional source](http://dangerousminds.net/comments/alec_guinness_a.k.a._obi_wan_kenobi_kind_of_hated_star_wars)).

Comment: I've seen at least one recounting of the Alec Guinness / fan conversation that pointed out that the timing worked out such that the child must have been watching the Star Wars film multiple times a day, clearly more than just a youthful fascination.

Comment: "I detected little star-shells of madness beginning to form"... that part is pure gold.

Comment: ROFL! That's just what I feel like saying to all the Star Wars fanatics on this site...

Comment: @randal'thor :D In all fairness, I *am* a Star Wars fan (OT only, pre most inane edits by Georgie). But I totally get what Guinness was saying, and he was hilarious (and a damn good actor). I disagree with him in his dislike of *any* escapist fantasy or scifi, not just the most absurd parts of Star Wars. Obsessive fans of any kind make me nervous as well, however.

Comment: And that little boy grew up to be.........Hayden Christensen