# Kenny Baker's attitude toward Star Wars

Tags: star-wars, droids, behind-the-scenes, r2-d2

<sub>inspired by [What has been Alec Guinness's attitude toward Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111996/alec-guinnesss-attitude-toward-star-wars)...</sub>

I've heard claims here and there about Kenny Baker's attitude toward the *Star Wars* franchise, with some claiming that he hates it or used to hate it, etc.

Did he like *Star Wars* and then grew to dislike it? Or vice versa? If he ever did dislike *Star Wars*, then **why?** etc.

Basically, what has been Kenny Baker's attitude(s) towards *Star Wars*?

Comment: @JakeGould Just FYI, I didn't ask this question (but I definitely inspired it). I did crack up when I saw it though, lol. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## TL;DR: He didn't love it - it was just a job. A difficult one too.

[image]

From a post on [StarWarsInterviews](http://starwarsinterviews1.blogspot.com/2010/01/kenny-baker-interview.html):

> **INTERVIEWER:** What do you regard as the highlight of your Star Wars career? Maybe a special moment or scene?
>
> **BAKER:** There weren’t any highlights; I was just there, in the droid. I was
> mainly in the end scenes of every movie. **I can’t remember any highs or
> lows, it was just a job.**
>
> **INTERVIEWER:** Still, it made you famous!
>
> **BAKER:** I’m not saying I didn’t enjoy it; it was just a job at that time. **It
> wasn’t a real acting job**.

And later:

> **INTERVIEWER:** Was it still comfortable for you?
>
> **BAKER:** No! Although it was better than in the beginning it is still
> **definitely not comfortable.** But then again, I got used to it.
>
> **INTERVIEWER:** …And you still enjoy being R2…
>
> **BAKER:** Well, **it wasn’t enjoyable** because I couldn’t react to the dialogue and
> everything that was happening around me, so **it wasn’t that easy**.
>
> **INTERVIEWER:** Most scenes you have done were with Anthony Daniels (C-3PO). How was
> it to work with him?
>
> **BAKER:** We were both in our droids; there was no interconnection at all. We
> couldn’t hear or see each other. George (Lucas) used to shout “look
> left, look right” and wanted me to project emotions like happiness and
> sadness. It wasn’t very easy, which also applies to C-3PO. He had to
> record his dialogue later on which had to match his movements. He had
> way more movement because he had arms and legs. **I didn’t have that, so
> it was very hard to communicate.** He came in an hour before me to get
> in the costume, while I just needed 5 minutes to get into R2. When we
> were done, they took the lid off and I am out! He needed another hour
> to get rid of the costume. So, we never met a lot.

---

**Bonus: While Baker seemed to be relatively OK with *Star Wars*, he *didn't* get along well with C-3PO actor Anthony Daniels**.

From an [article on Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3242916/Robot-wars-Actor-played-C-3PO-reveals-39-year-feud-R2-D2-star-played-branded-rudest-man-met.html):

> R2-D2 star Kenny Baker, 83, once branded C-3PO, or Anthony Daniels as he's otherwise known, 'the rudest man I’ve ever met'.

This [article from Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/star-wars-the-force-awakens/c3po-actor-r2d2-feud/) goes on to describe the tension between Baker and Daniels.

Main points:

- > It was the rudest thing anyone had ever done to me
- > It was very hard to communicate [with Daniels]
- > If he comes [to an interview], I won’t be there
- > He looked down his nose at me
- > I don’t hate Daniels…I just don’t like him