# Which TNG actors were TOS fans?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, behind-the-scenes

[image: Picture of the TNG cast. From the top left: Wesley Crusher (Wil Wheaton), Tasha Yar (Denise Crosby), Worf (Michael Dorn), Data (Brent Spiner), Geordi La Forge (LeVar Burton), William Riker (Jonathan Frakes), Deanna Trao (Marina Sirtis), Jean-Luc Picard (Patrick Stewart), Beverly Crusher (Gates McFadden).]

**Were any of the *The Next Generation* actors self-professed fans of *The Original Series* before being cast as characters in *TNG*?**

(Or did they all think it was just [fairy tale rubbish](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111996/what-has-been-alec-guinnesss-attitude-toward-star-wars)?)

I'm only interested in the first-billed actors — not guest stars or minor recurring roles.

Comment: So not Guinan then 

Comment: This is turning out to be **much** harder than I had anticipated!  Great question

Comment: Only 142 views on this question?! Bounty started.

Comment: @randal'thor : Thanks! That should draw some attention.  :-)

Comment: I’m re-watching season 1 at the moment. They all look so young, except for Patrick Stewart, who somehow always looks exactly the same age.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite : Ditto for Tommy Lee Jones and Anthony Hopkins.  :-)

Comment: I was hoping this'd get at least a Nice Question badge by the time the bounty ran out. Ah well.

Comment: @randal'thor : Ah, that's okay, the badge doesn't matter.  I'm just glad the question piqued your interest, and I appreciate your generosity.  :-)

Comment: Patrick Stewart has stated that his kids watched TOS but he himself never did.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Will Wheaton, the actor who played Wesley Crusher is very open about the fact that he is a nerd, and a fan of the original series.  He's written himself numerous times about his experiences being a fan while also being on the show, such as [on this Facebook post](https://m.facebook.com/itswilwheaton/posts/306067969519752) where he mentions he was attending Star Trek conventions long before he was ever asked to be a guest at one.

I have found a number of sources where the fact that he was a fan of the original series before he was cast as Wesley Crusher is pretty strongly implied, such as [in this interview](http://www.avclub.com/article/wil-wheaton-13792)  where he had said of his audition for the role of Wesley Crusher:

> It's kind of intimidating meeting Gene Roddenberry—it was like meeting
>   Arthur C. Clarke or somebody—but he was a great guy, and I ended up
>   getting the job.

[Another quote from an interview](http://www.tv.com/m/news/wil-wheaton-interview-star-trek-tng-remastered-on-blu-ray-29459/) with him done regarding the remastered *Star Trek: The Next Generation* Blu ray:

> Most, at first, thought that he was the luckiest 15-year-old in the
>   galaxy, able to work with greats like Patrick Stewart in a sequel of a
>   series that he was both a fan of and that already had large fan
>   following.

In addition, I've found a [youtube video of an interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hccLhbBHlM4) with Wil Wheaton that is said to have been recorded before *Star Trek: The Next Generation* has aired, in which is said:

> Narrator:  Born after the original series went off the air, Wil
>   Wheaton, the youngest member of the cast of Star Trek The Next
>   Generation considers himself, without a doubt, to be a fan.
>
> Wil Wheaton:  I'm a Trekkie, but not the kind of Trekkie that knows
>   everything about the show.  I couldn't tell you like who starred in
>   episode number 13, you know, in the second half, who was the main
>   focus, or anything like that.  Um, what I do is I like to read the
>   books.  The novels I haven't really gotten into yet.  But like the
>   comic book I read, the old series I watch every night, unless I have
>   to get up real, real early for work the next day.

Finally, I cite a definitive quote from [Wil Wheaton's own blog](http://wilwheaton.net/2014/09/star-trek-is-48-years-old-this-week/), where Wil Wheaton refers to playing *Star Trek* as a kid, nearly ten years before he got his role on *The Next Generation*:

> When I was a little kid, playing Star Trek on the playground (I always
>   ended up being Spock), I had no idea that less than a decade later it
>   would become a fundamental part of the tapestry of my life.

Comment: But specifically, did he like *The Original Series* before he was cast as Wesley Crusher?

Comment: @Praxis Updated, as far as I've been able to find so far.

Comment: @Praxis Finally, I have found an explicit quote by Wil Wheaton.  =)

Comment: @Kai : That's perfect!  I'll leave it open until the end of the bounty period, just in case anything else emerges.  :-)

Comment: @randal'thor : Kai found a great quote from Wheaton.  You might want to wait a few days to award the bounty, just in case something else is found on other actors, but in my opinion this answer is now bounty-worthy. :-)

Comment: @Praxis Definitely. I'll wait a few days so the question and answer keep getting attention and upvotes, and in case anything even better comes along, but it looks like +100 for Kai fairly soon :-)

Comment: Nice finds, and thoroughly researched answer. Bounty awarded and well earned.

Answer (score 16):

## Levar Burton and Brent Spiner were but Gates McFadden wasn't

I'm live-answering this from the **Star Trek 50th Anniversary Celebration in Las Vegas.**

Gates McFadden, Levar Burton, and Brent Spiner are currently on stage.

> **SPINER:** My first impression when they announced a new Star Trek show [*TNG*] was "Why?? The original one was perfect."
>
> **BURTON:** I was a huge fan of *The Original Series* growing up.
>
> **McFADDEN:** I didn't watch the original show at all before the announcement of the new show.

Comment: *WAY TO POOP THE PARTY MCFADDEN*