# Whose idea was it to kill off this character?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

To fans (myself included) seeing a lot of the old cast return was a huge leap back to my childhood. But for some, the role wasn't all that exciting.

In a lot of interviews about the return to the role of Han Solo, Harrison Ford provided a few statements that came across (with his usual "grumpy" attitude) that the role was not all that exciting.

> “Well, I didn’t have a job,” he says with a wry grin.
>
> [...]At 73, Ford is one of the few action heroes who can also claim senior citizen status, which might explain his hesitation at returning to this iconic role.

[Source](http://www.news.com.au/entertainment/movies/new-movies/harrison-ford-reveals-why-he-returned-to-dumb-han-solo-character/news-story/ab9bd0cb210d4aedb7f9120a12771300)

As well as a bit of a joke line from the movie that branches off from a real-life experience that [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/124078/46407) covers:

> "Are you Harrison Ford?"/"Are you Han Solo?"
>
> "I used to be..."

There was also another interview that involved him, Daisy Ridley and John Boyega in which he refused to talk about his role, and instead focused on the Ridley and Boyega's involvement in the movie (with some excitement, from memory).

So my question is:

> Whose idea was it to kill off Han Solo?

Comment: Now that I think about it... this might be better off on movies.SE...

Comment: It's a good solid question.  Please leave it here.  We need more like this - discussing what's really going on and the motivations behind the writing.  We handle a lot of "in universe" questions, which is helpful, but questions like this are good for SF&F as well.

Comment: Also, for the record, I upvoted this question.  I know new users can be sensitive about duplicates, so let me be clear that "duplicate" is not a mark of shame --- it means your question is good enough to have been asked before!  Also, please note that you will not lose the reputation you have earned from this question.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis I've been on this site for a while, (mainly over on gaming.se) so I know how the system rolls. I just seem to have a different way of asking the same question a lot of the time haha.

Comment: @Ben : Okay, cool.  I wasn't sure how much exposure you had to the system, so I just wanted to make sure you were fine with this.  :-)